# How do you update Intellicode Model in Visual Studio Enterprise 2022

Tags: c#, intellisense, visual-studio-2022, intellicode

I am wondering if there is the feature to retrain my intellicode model through Visual Studio 2022. I did find the question answered in 2019 through the url here: [How do I update my IntelliCode model in Visual Studio 2019?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57342054/how-do-i-update-my-intellicode-model-in-visual-studio-2019/57527927#57527927)

However, that link does not have the path to access that windows shown in the screenshot. I tried looking in the Views/Options section of Visual Studio but I am not able to find anything. Not sure if this is still a feature or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't find this window anymore.  [It was removed](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/IntelliCode-is-missing-in-View---Other/10369264?sort=newest&topics=visual%20studio%202019) (or replaced rather by the machine learning model):

> the team completions model has been replaced with a deep learning model that provides the same functionality without the need to train new models.
> The other benefit is none of your code needs to be inferenced against a cloud server to produce a model with this new capability:

You previously could find this window that is referenced in the post you linked to by going to View → Other Windows → Intellicode.

A more detailed blog post can be found [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/upgrading-from-intellicode-custom-team-completions-models-to-deep-learning/) about the deep learning model.  You may also find [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/retrain-model-ml-net) helpful with regards to re-training a machine learning model.